# sql is duplicating my results

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I believe the problem is within my joins but i am unable to correct it. The SQL should return 3 rows however it is duplicating and returning 12 rows instead. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
SELECT J.JOURNEY_NUMBER,
  L.DESCRIPTION,
  L.USE_CODE,
  J.REAL_START_DATE,
  J.REAL_END_DATE,
  S.STOP_ID,
  SN.WRIN_ID,
  J.JOURNEY_ID
FROM PDA_STG.JOURNEY J,
  PDA_STG.RESTAURANT R,
  PDA_STG.LOCATION L,
  PDA_STG.SERIAL_NUMBER SN,
  PDA_STG.STOP S
WHERE J.JOURNEY_ID = R.JOURNEY_ID
AND l.loc_id       = r.rest_loc_id
AND J.JOURNEY_ID   = S.JOURNEY_ID
AND S.STOP_ID      = SN.STOP_ID
AND SN.WRIN_ID     = '00768669'
AND j.dc_loc_id = '994'
AND J.JOURNEY_ID = '357020'
AND J.PLANNED_START_DATE < '20-APR-17'
ORDER BY J.JOURNEY_ID DESC
```

Comment: There is no way to answer your question without knowing what the data in those tables looks like and what you expect as a result. Please add some samples to give us a chance to help you out here.

Comment: You probably forgot a join criteria. We cannot say, because we don't know your tables.

Comment: without sample it's difficult to tell what's wrong with the query. But if rows are exact duplicate then just put a distinct after select. That should do the job

Comment: Side notes: You are using an out-dated join error-prone syntax. Please use ANSI joins instead (`FROM PDA_STG.JOURNEY J JOIN PDA_STG.RESTAURANT R ON J.JOURNEY_ID = R.JOURNEY_ID`). Also you should never compare dates with strings. Especially not such with names ('APR') in it. You are relying on settings that can be different and make your query fail. Use ANSI date literals instead (`AND J.PLANNED_START_DATE < DATE '2017-04-20'`). Are all your IDs strings? If they are number, you should treat them so (e.g. `AND j.dc_loc_id = 994`).

Comment: @India.Rocket: Yes it should. But it's always better to find the cause and fix it.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner completely agree with you. But there's no sample here for us to work on it and  fix it

Answer (score 2):

You are probably joining records that you don't want to join for which you'd have to add some join criteria. (For instance if the serial number could change for a stop, i.e. you keep old serial numbers with a date, you'd only want the latest serial number, not all.)

In order to find the flaw in your query you can `select *` and see what records you are actually selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, i just done as India.Rocket said and it worked perfectly.

> without sample it's difficult to tell what's wrong with the query. But
>   if rows are exact duplicate then just put a distinct after select.
>   That should do the job – India.Rocket 46 mins ago

Comment: And as I said in a comment - and India.Rocket agreed - this is a kind of last resort. You should rather find your mistake and correct it, instead of muddling through with `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` is very often an indicator for a poorly written query (as in your case) and can lead both to performance problems and other issues when extending the query later. In summary: Don't do this.